# marshal.loads function does not load *.pyc contents to code object

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I Try this in Python 3.3

```
f = open(r'somewhere\my_module.pyc','rb')
contents = f.read()
f.close()

code_obj = marshal.loads(contents[8:])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
```

I get error , so i convert `contents` variable type to `str`

```
def bytes2str(byte_seq):
    str_seq = ''
    for b in byte_seq:
        str_seq += chr(b)
    return str_seq

contents = bytes2str(contents)
code_obj = marshal.loads(contents[8:])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

When i try this in Python 2.7 i get a code object. How to deal with this problem without using `compile` built-in function?

Answer (score 6):

It seems the header of a `.pyc` file has changed in recent versions of Python to be 12 bytes, rather than 8. If you do `code_obj = marshal.loads(contents[12:])`, you'll get the code object you are seeking.

I've tried in vain to find documentation of this change to the PYC file format, but so far I've not had any luck. It seems like it started with Python 3.3 (which included quite a lot of changes to the import machinery), but I'm not sure which bit required the extra 4 bytes.

Comment: python 3.7 increased the header size from 12 to 16